# Returning to wrong activity after application got killed by OS

Tags: android, operating-system

Some of the customers of my application claims that when they return to my application after it has been in background for a while they get to the activity they haven't left from. The view (activity) they leave is a form for which I provide all the staff with serializing data in onSavedInstanceState and recovering it on return. And what they say is that sometimes they return to 1 activity before the form (1 below in activity stack). How is this possible ?

So tested the whole thing. I put my app in background and killed it with DDMS. Also I just turned screen off, killed it with DDMS. Everything is fine. I stay in the form view and all form's data are recovered.

There is a situation that when I kill my app when it's in foreground (active). Then I indeed get pushed 1 activity back. But it's happening for all places in application, not only for the form. However it's really unlikely that OS will kill foreground application. Or am I wrong ?

Is there any other scenario this behavior may occur ?

Comment: What version do your customers test on? And what android version do you test on?

Comment: Customer: Android 2.3.6
Me: Android 4.1, 2.3.6

Comment: Did you try this: go to your form, press home and then kill your app with ddms?

Comment: Yes I do this. I also tested it when I turned screen off. The result is I kill it and I return properly. The customer doesn't say he has this bug all the time but just sometimes.